# Get rid of case sensitive username in custom membership provider

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-membership, case-sensitive, custom-membershipprovider

I implemented a custom membership provider in ASP.net MVC, and can't figure out how to make the username non case-sensitive at signin.  So, for example, "Solomon" could log in, but "solomon" could not.

My implementation is very bare bones.  I basically just wrote code for ValidateUser(), and Change Password().

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you call database in ValidateUser()? If yes, you should make query not case sensitive. What database do you use?

Comment: I'm using a MySql database with Fluent Nhibernate as my orm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shimms is halfway there.

Splitting a logical operation between two 'tiers' is not a sound practice.

A logical operation should be atomic. So just lower both in the query...

e.g.

```
where Lower(username)=Lower(@username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the username to its lowercase version, and then compare it to the lowercase version of the username in the database.  The ANSI SQL would be:

```
WHERE LOWER(username) = :username
```

Supply the username parameter as:

```
... = username.ToLower();
```

Comment: You have a brittle logical dependency here, shimms. You should not split a logical operation. This should be an atomic comparison in the database/query.